# $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(e^{\frac{-1}{x}})$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I know that the $\lim_{x\to 0}  \sin(e^{\frac{-1}{x}}) =0$ by simply knowing the fact that as $\lim_{x\to 0} e^{{\frac{-1}{x}}}=0$ and this implies $\sin(0)=0$.

In order to verify the limit, i calculated right hand limit which comes out to be 0. But i am stuck at calculating left hand limit. it comes out that the right hand limit do not exist. Isn't it?

Comment: How is the left hand limit $0$

Comment: whoops, sorry. typing error.Corrected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RHL**

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin (e^{\frac{-1}{x}})=\lim _{h\to 0}\sin (e^{\frac{-1}{h}})$

As $h\to 0\implies \frac{1}{h}\to \infty \implies e^{\frac{-1}{h}}\to 0\implies \sin (e^{\frac{-1}{x}})\to 0$

So $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin (e^{\frac{-1}{x}})=0$

**LHL**

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sin (e^{\frac{-1}{x}})=\lim _{h\to 0}\sin (e^{\frac{1}{h}})$

As $h\to 0\implies \frac{1}{h}\to \infty \implies e^{\frac{1}{h}}\to \infty$

Hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: You need to be more careful and write $h\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x)=\sin(e^{-1/x})$. You can prove it by using sequences (Heine definition): note that $x_n=-\frac{1}{\ln(\frac{\pi}{2}n)}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, but
$$
f(x_n)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \hbox{in $n$ is even}\\
\pm1 & \hbox{in $n$ is odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ does not exist.